# C# Asychronous REST query not working: WaitAll or WhenAll combined with .Result hangs up

Tags: c#, rest

I am building a C# Winforms application and I have many REST calls to process. Each call takes about 10 sec till I receive an answer, so in the end, my application is running quite a while. Mostly spending time waiting for the REST service to answer.

I am not coming forward because no matter what I try (configureAwait, waitAll or whenAll), the application hangs or when I want to access each tasks result, it is going back to the Main methods or hangs. Here is what I currently have:

I am building up a list of tasks to fill my objects :

```cs
List<Task> days = new List<Task>();

for (DateTime d = dtStart; d <= dtEnd; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    if (UseProduct)
    {
        Task _t = AsyncBuildDay(d, Project, Product, fixVersion);
        var t = _t as Task<Day>;
        days.Add(t);
    }
    else
    {
        Task _t = AsyncBuildDay(d, Project, fixVersion);
        var t = _t as Task<Day>;
        days.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Then I am starting and waiting until every task is finished and the objects are built:

```cs
Task.WaitAll(days.ToArray());
```

When I try this, then the tasks are waiting for activation:

```cs
var tks = Task.WhenAll(days.ToArray());
```

What is running asynchronously inside the tasks (AsyncBuildDay
) is a query to JIRA:

```cs
private async Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(JIRAUser + ":" + JIRAPassword));
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(JIRAUser, JIRAPassword);
    WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    // Read the content fully up to the end.
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return json;
}
```

And now I would like to access all my objects with .Result, but then the whole code freezes again.

```
foreach (Task<Day> t in days)
{
    dc.colDays.Add(t.Result);
}
```

I don't find a wait to get to my objects and I'm really going nuts with this stuff. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this.

`Task.WhenAll` is the way to go; it returns a new `Task` that completes when the provided tasks have all completed.

It's also non-blocking.

By `await`ing the `Task` returned by `Task.WhenAll`, you unwrap it's results into an array:

```
List<Task<Day>> dayTasks = new();
// ...
Day[] days = await Task.WhenAll(dayTasks);
```

You can then add this to `dc.colDays`:

```
dc.colDays.AddRange(days);
```

Or if `dc.colDays` doesnt have an `AddRange` method:

```
foreach (var day in days) dc.colDays.Add(day);
```

Comment: It seems there is a little typo. Shouldn't it be:  `Task.WhenAll(dayTasks)`

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to await any completion, and remove the completed task from the list.

```
   while (days.Count > 0)
   {
        
        Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(days);      

        // Do something with result.

        days.Remove(completedTask);
    }
```